# Reading and setting lock screen password/pattern on Android devices within an app

Tags: android, passwords, locking, screen, setting

Hello stackoverflow users!

I'm making an app that requires reading and setting the lock screen password depending on which state the app is in.

Is there a way to do this without rooting? Or are there any alternatives like making the user reset the password for the different states so the app avoids the problems involved in reading the already existing password?

Just to make things clearer:

App state 1: pattern screen lock password

*app changes screen lock password to state 2*

App state 2: no password (slide screen lock)

Thank you in advance,

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to change the lock screen password is to make use of the device administrator class. Do note that it is only for Android 3.0 and up.

Here is the [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html/)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!
Will this class be able to change the password without prompt?

Comment: Yes but the user must allow the app to have device admin rights before it can be done.